# How to force am/pm selection in time input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

We have a form where users have to fill out time input fields and on change it auto saves the entries.  We're nervous that some of our users won't know to select the am/pm option.  Unfortunately, if I try to do a blur on the field and then check the value of it, even if it's set to something like 08:00 it has a value of empty.  It doesn't actually have a value until am/pm is selected.  Does anyone know of a way to force a selection of am/pm when there is some beginning of a time value in the field?

Here's a short snippet of the code in question.

```
<input type="time" class="form-control save_el">

$(".save_el").on("change", function () {
    doSomething($(this));
});
```

The change event only fires once a time with am/pm is selected.  Simply putting in 08:00 doesn't fire the change event.

Comment: What about 24 hr format? No need for am/pm.

Comment: Being in the states, most of our users are used to a 12 hour format so that might be an issue too.

Comment: This good library for time picking https://www.cssscript.com/demo/highly-customizable-date-and-time-picker-with-rome-js/

Comment: Thanks but we're trying to stick with the browser implementation.

Comment: Missing some context. Can you post the HTML of the fields, and the onchange function?

Comment: Code added for reference.

Comment: *"but we're trying to stick with the browser implementation."*: in that case you will have to live with different implementations in different browsers, which may or may not implement `type=time`, which may or may not take the locale settings (concerning 12-hour or 24-hour format) into account. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time).